# Problems in Isometric Tiled game using cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, isometric

I've been trying to make sense of the [Knight Fight](https://github.com/lozarcher/KnightFight) isometric game made wih [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org)

This particular function is giving me different results when I opened a fresh project and loaded the same map.

```
-(CGPoint) locationFromTilePos:(CGPoint)tilePos;
{
    CCTMXLayer *grass = [self.tileMap layerNamed:@"Grass"];
    CCSprite *tile = [grass tileAt:tilePos];
    float x = -tile.position.x - self.tileMap.tileSize.width + 32;
    float y = -tile.position.y - self.tileMap.tileSize.height;
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

When feeding in tilePos as (0,0) in Knight Fight

1. Grass Tile position : (1248, 1248)
2. Final location returned by function : (-1280,-1280)

When feeding in tilePos as (0,0) in my fresh project

1. Grass Tile position : (624, 624)
2. Final location returned by function : (-656,-656)

I cannot find any resource online for Isometric Maps on Cocos2d using Tiled. I need to convert between tile coordinates and real screen coordinates. Can anyone help.

Comment: That project is about a year old, and is using cocos2d-iPhone v .99.5 , which I believe is before it had support for retina devices. You might try upgrading the cocos2d version, and fixing the issues that come up( in this case, I would upgrade to 1.1, not 2.x, as the upgrade path is easier)

Comment: ok so the difference in values is because of older cocos2d version? Also, could you pls point me to any resource where I can study isometric maps with Tiled and accessing the coordinates in cocos2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:
   // calculate screen coordinates from tile coordinates

```
- (CGPoint)positionForTileCoord:(CGPoint)pos {

float halfMapWidth = _tileMap.mapSize.width*0.5;
float halfMapHeight = _tileMap.mapSize.height*0.5;
float tileWidth = _tileMap.tileSize.width;
float tileHeight = _tileMap.tileSize.height;

int convertedY = _tileMap.mapSize.height-(pos.y-1);

int x = halfMapWidth*tileWidth + tileWidth*pos.x*0.5-tileWidth*pos.y*0.5;
int y = halfMapHeight*tileHeight +tileHeight*convertedY*0.5 - tileHeight*pos.x*0.5-tileHeight*0.5;


return ccp(x, y);

}
```

and for the opposite try this:

```
// calculating the tile coordinates from screen location

-(CGPoint) tilePosFromLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
CGPoint pos = location;
float halfMapWidth = _tileMap.mapSize.width*0.5;
float mapHeight = _tileMap.mapSize.height;
float tileWidth = _tileMap.tileSize.width;
float tileHeight = _tileMap.tileSize.height;

CGPoint tilePosDiv = CGPointMake(pos.x/tileWidth, pos.y/tileHeight);
float invereseTileY = mapHeight - tilePosDiv.y;

// Cast int to make sure that result is in whole numbers

float posX = (int)(invereseTileY + tilePosDiv.x - halfMapWidth);
float posY = (int)(invereseTileY - tilePosDiv.x + halfMapWidth);

return CGPointMake(posX, posY);
}
```

Comment: float posX = (int)(invereseTileY + tilePosDiv.x - halfMapWidth);
float posY = (int)(invereseTileY - tilePosDiv.x + halfMapWidth);
Didnt get this part

Comment: These will be your X and Y Tile Map coordinates, calculated from screen coordinates.

Comment: I meant I couldn't understand the logic correctly. I completely understood the logic behind tile coordinates for Orthogonal map. I got the part where we divide touch coordinate by tile width n height. But the next step is what I dont get.

Comment: the halfMapWidth part is due to the fact that the map is skued, if you draw it on paper, you'll see how it come is place, since when moving on the x axis for example you are also moving down the Y screen coordinates.